# Multiple types were found that match the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to `api versioning` using `header` but in `different folder structure` like below.

In `Controller folder` have `V1` sub folder inside that `CustomerController.cs`
and

In `Controller folder` have `V2` sub folder inside that `CustomerController.cs`

when I user api version using `URL` above works fine.

my issue is When I try this approach with `header` it is giving me below error:

> {   "Message": "An error has occurred.",   "ExceptionMessage":
>   "Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'customer'.
>   This can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('api/{controller}/{id}') found multiple controllers defined with the
>   same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported.\r\n\r\nThe
>   request for 'customer' has found the following matching
>   controllers:\r\nApiVersion.Controllers.V1.CustomerController\r\nApiVersion.Controllers.V2.CustomerController",   "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",   "StackTrace": "
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
>   }

WebApiConfig.cs

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

CustomeControllerSelector.cs

```
        public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var controllers = GetControllerMapping();
            var routeData = request.GetRouteData();
            var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            //HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor;

            var version = GetVersionFromAcceptHeaderVersion(request);
            var controllerKey = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.{1}",
                        version, controllerName);


            //if (controllers.TryGetValue(controllerName, out controllerDescriptor))
            // {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(version))
            {
                HttpControllerDescriptor versionedControllerDescriptor;
                if (controllers.TryGetValue(controllerKey, out versionedControllerDescriptor))
                {
                    return versionedControllerDescriptor;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

          private string GetVersionFromAcceptHeaderVersion(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var acceptHeader = request.Headers.Accept;
            foreach (var mime in acceptHeader)
            {
                if (mime.MediaType == "application/json" || mime.MediaType == "text/html")
                {
                    var version = mime.Parameters
                                    .Where(v => v.Name.Equals("version", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
                    if (version != null)
                    {
                        return version.Value;
                    }
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following. Works as of now -

```
public class CustomControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    //const string partName = "Webapi.Controllers";
    private readonly HttpConfiguration _config;

    public CustomControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config)
        : base(config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public override System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var _route = request.GetRouteData();

        var controllerName = base.GetControllerName(request);

        var type = _config.Services.GetAssembliesResolver();
        var controlles = _config.Services.GetHttpControllerTypeResolver().GetControllerTypes(type);

        object name;
        _route.Values.TryGetValue("route", out name);

        //No more hard coding
        var partName = controllers.FirstOrDefault().Namespace;
        var st = name as string;
        if (st != null)
        {
            var conType = controlles.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Namespace == string.Format("{0}.{1}", partName, st));
                        if (conType != null)
                            return new System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor(_config, controllerName, conType);
        }

        return base.SelectController(request);
    }
}
```

In the WebApiConfig.cs -

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{route}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Test routes -

```
http://localhost:60957/api/Another/Route/a
http://localhost:60957/api/Another/Route2/aaaaa
```

Comment: No my call is like `http://localhost:58892/api/customer` and in header `accept : application/json;version=1`

what you did is static :( check my class `CustomeControllerSelector.cs
`

Comment: yes it is working fine when Controller is in Controller folder `CustomerV1Controller.cs` and `CustomerV2Controller.cs` and code is

             `var versionedControllerName = string.Concat(controllerName, "V", version);
                HttpControllerDescriptor versionedControllerDescriptor;
                if (controllers.TryGetValue(versionedControllerName, out versionedControllerDescriptor))
                {
                    return versionedControllerDescriptor;
                }`

Comment: this is null :( why I dont know 
                `if (controllers.TryGetValue(controllerKey, out versionedControllerDescriptor))`

Comment: what is `Webapi.Controllers` in my code I have not used it.

Comment: this is also null `_route.Values.TryGetValue("route", out name);
`

Comment: That is the common part of namespaces for my controllers. You need to change your routing code as well to include the `route` part.

Comment: last question how can i take this name dynamically `Webapi.Controllers`?

Comment: I'm also looking for the same. Will update if found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100359/discussion-between-neo-and-amit-kumar-ghosh).