# Need To use Identical Controllers in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How can i use two identical Controllers in Web API 2.

I need to use URL as follows.

```
mysite/api/Contacts/get/2
```

and

```
mysite/api/v1/Contacts/get/2
```

but if i use seperate folder for this it gives an error.

my WebApiConfig.cs like this

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi2",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

This is the Error

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'default'.
>   This can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('api/v1/{controller}/{id}') found multiple controllers defined with
>   the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported. The
>   request for 'default' has found the following matching controllers:
>   TestWebAPI.Controllers.DefaultController
>   TestWebAPI.Controllers.v1.DefaultController

How Can i Achieve this?... Basically I need this for Versioning.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: from what i see you're trying to acces this link : `mysite/api/version1/Contacts/get/2` but the route is registering this: `mysite/api/v1/Contacts/get/2`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715625/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller/34716586#34716586

Comment: i have added the error

Comment: Use url rewriting? Rewrite the non-version to the version specific URL.

Comment: You could try with attribute routing, that should work since the rout is set up inside of the controller. The attribute needs to be placed on top of your method and it looks like this: `[Route('your/route/here')]`. You also need this using statement: `using AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc;` and add this to your RegisterRoutes method in your RoutesConfig: `routes.MapAttributeRoutes();`

Answer (score 0):

> This can happen if the route that services this request ('api/v1/{controller}/{id}') found multiple controllers defined with the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported.

This means that you have two distinct controllers named `DefaultController` (as you mentioned).

If you want to serve both urls with the same controller, just delete the one in `v1` folder. If you want to serve each url with each controller you should specify the namespace for each one.

```
var r = routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
r.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = new string[] {"Foo"};
```

More info in this [blog post](http://shazwazza.com/post/multiple-webapi-controllers-with-the-same-name-but-different-namespaces/).